# How to settle payments in authorize.net sandbox?

Tags: transactions, authorize.net, authorize.net-arb

I need to refund a transaction for testing ..that was created on 2 days ago..i have receive silent post notification that the payment has been approved..but still its not showing in the settled transactions its a recurring billing payment and payment count is showing  1 of outgoing..i am confused that why it is not showing in settled transactions.
Please help

Comment: Was this an AuthCapture or an Auth_Only transaction?  An Auth_Only transaction would remain in a authorized pending capture state until a prior  AuthCapture was issued.

Comment: @Shivika Sharma, Did you get any updated for this question?

Answer (score 2):

The sandbox does not process actual payments so payments are never settled.

Comment: It is true that the sandbox does not process actual payments, but it does include a processor simulator that mimics the settlement process like it would in production.

Comment: So it's actually impossible to write a test for refund that will always work...! :(